# Better looking raceway for under the patio?

Tags: electrical

Is there a better looking conduit that would be per code that I can place under the patio root. It will be visible, and the gray sch. 40 looks bad. Is there anything better looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can paint it. Given that it's presumably an exterior location, none of the other acceptable options really look all that much better. Either paint or enclosing in a trim box are your likley good options for "better looking."

Edit, responding to comment: Terminology nitpick - sweeps or bends - we never use "elbows" in conduit, you can't pull wire around a sharp bend. Same in ground or out of ground. What you do need (and want, though you may think otherwise when you see the price) is a conduit expansion joint at each place where you go from underground to above-ground.

[image: Expansion joint picture from Madison Electrical products]

If you don't use them, the conduit can be broken as the ground freezes and thaws. Ideally you will also use schedule 80 if the conduit is "subject to damage" which the part coming out of the ground is often taken to be - if you haven't bought it yet, I'd suggest considering schedule 80 for the whole run, though it means you will have to shop a real electrical supplier, not a home improvement store. It costs only a little bit more in most cases.

You will also do yourself a favor if you clean up any sharp edges on the inside end of the conduit before assembly.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. One more if you don't mind. Is the same conduit used then I come up, from the ground up the post to subpanel. Are there any special rules. Are the same elbows used to make 90 turn in ground as they are above ground?

Comment: Yes, I am shopping at real electrical supply, prices at HD or Lowes are almost double than at Elliott :). And yes, I will be using 45 and 90 degree sweeps also. Now these are cheaper at HD, go figure.

Comment: All I can find online are 2" ones. Is that the smallest size? I need some kind of adapter then?

Comment: Your electrical supplier should have them in any size you need. I certainly have them on 1" conduit, and they are 1" expansion joints, not an adapted size.

Comment: @epitka, I'd read [this](http://www.carlonsales.com/techinfo/installationtraining/IT-NEMAEXJTA.pdf) before I went crazy with expansion joints. Not to nitpick, but there's nothing you've said here that would make me think you'd need one, and especially not where it stubs out of the ground. Although it's possible but entirely based on the situation - so check before.

Comment: That ^ is completely irrlevent to the reason for using them where the conduit comes out of the ground. The reason for doing so is to deal with movement from the ground (with the buried part of the conduit in it) freezing and thawing, not expansion or contraction of hundreds of feet of conduit. I hardly think two expansion joints is "going crazy with them" and I have seen the aftermath of people skipping them - conduits broken between the above-ground termination and the ground. If @epitika lives in a non-freezing climate, sure, skip them.

Comment: PVC pipe breaks in cold climates because it makes it brittle. The opposite, making it pliable, when it gets hot. I'm saying, after running copious amounts of all sizes of PVC - stubbing them up/down/around, I've never used on in that situation nor have I seen an "aftermath" of their lack of use; it's simply not their intended purpose; that's what that ^^ was for. Using 1 when 0 are needed is going crazy - IMHO of course.

Comment: My electric utility thinks otherwise (actually, virtually all utilities in the state have agreed.) http://www.greenmountainpower.com/upload/photos/323BOOK1112.pdf 507 B. 1. l. *An expansion coupling is required at the point where the conduit emerges from the ground. The coupling should be placed a minimum of twelve (12) inches above final ground grade.*

Comment: That's a utility spec about services; it's pretty irrelevant to the question. If you have dealt with an EU on a new construction job you know that's their own code that *they* (EUs) write and are governed by much greater responsibility. What OP does in his back yard isn't even comparable. Show me where your local Electrical Code requires it. Further, that only says to require it and doesn't say why. So your claim hasn't been substantiated by it. It could be just as well for temperature change of the exposed pipe which is what the link was about.

Comment: Finally, my initial comment boiled down to - check before you do. I still stand by that.

Comment: I see the reason why one should use it, but I live in TX, ground is pretty compact where the wires will it comes out, and none of my neighbors have one on their control centers and houses are more than 10 years old.